# How to use redux stores to store data coming from API

Tags: typescript, redux

I am creating a custom reusable data table. I am having a scenario where I have to store API data using stores. For that I have a fake API which is having some records. And using reacts useState I am fetching the data as

```
fetchData = async () => {
try {
  const response = await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts');
  const data = await response.json();

  console.log('Received data:', data);

  this.setState({
    products: data,
  });
} catch (error) {
  console.error('Error fetching data:', error);
}};
```

But my requirement is to use stores from redux.

```js
// Import necessary libraries and components.
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import CustomDataTable from './datatable-component/Data table/customDataTable';
import { ProductService } from './datatable-component/mockData';
import { Chip } from './datatable-component/chip/chip';
import { Column } from 'primereact/column';
import { DateFormatter } from './datatable-component/Data table/formatter';
import './App.css';
import { DateFilter, DropdownFilter } from './datatable-component/Data table/filterComponnet';

// Define the interface for the application's state.
interface AppState {
  sortField: string | null; // Current sort field for the table.
  sortOrder: number; // Current sort order (1 for ascending, -1 for descending).
  selectedRows: any[]; // Array of selected rows.
  selectAll: boolean; // Indicates whether all rows are selected.
  scrollHeight: string; // Height of the table scroll area.
  scrollWidth: string; // Width of the table scroll area.
  direction: 'ascending' | 'descending'; // Current sorting direction.
  products: any[];
}

export interface RowData {
  userId: number;
  id: number; 
  code: string; 
  name: string; 
  description: string; 
  price: number; 
  status: string; 
  severity: string; 
  date: string; 
}

// Create the main application component.
class App extends Component<{}, AppState> {

  constructor(props: {}) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      sortField: null, // Initially, no sort field is selected.
      sortOrder: 1, // Initially, sorting is in ascending order.
      selectedRows: [], // Initially, no rows are selected.
      selectAll: false, // Initially, the "select all" option is unchecked.
      scrollHeight: '900', // Initial height of the table scroll area.
      scrollWidth: '960', // Initial width of the table scroll area.
      direction: 'ascending', // Initial sorting direction is ascending.
      products: []
    };
  }

  // Define a function to render a Chip component based on a value.
  getChip(value: string) {
    const options = [
      { value: 'High', text: 'HIGH' },
      { value: 'Medium', text: 'MEDIUM' },
      { value: 'Low', text: 'LOW' },
    ];
    const selectedOption = options.find((option) => option.value === value);
    let view: any = null;
    switch (selectedOption?.value) {
      case 'High':
        view = <Chip label={'HIGH'} color={'red-white'} />;
        break;
      case 'Medium':
        view = <Chip label={'MEDIUM'} color={'yellow'} />;
        break;
      case 'Low':
        view = <Chip label={'LOW'} color={'blue-white'} />;
        break;
      default:
        break;
    }

    return view;
  }

  renderFilterComponent(field: string) {
    switch (field) {
      case 'date':
        return <DateFilter onFilterChange={(value) => console.log(value)} />;
      case 'status':
        return <DropdownFilter options={['HIGH', 'MEDIUM', 'LOW']} onFilterChange={(value) => console.log(value)} />;
      default:
        return null;
    }
  }

  // Define a function to handle sorting changes.
  handleSortChange = (field: string, order: number) => {
    this.setState({ sortField: field, sortOrder: order });
  };

  // Define a function to handle selection changes.
  handleSelectionChange = (selectedRows: any[], selectAll: boolean) => {
    this.setState({ selectedRows, selectAll });
  };

  fetchData = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts');
      const data = await response.json();
  
      console.log('Received data:', data);
  
      this.setState({
        products: data,
      });
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error fetching data:', error);
    }
  };
  
  componentDidMount() {
    this.fetchData();
  }
  
  getHeader(field: string) {
    return field.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + field.slice(1);
  }

  IdRenderer = (rowData: RowData) => {
    return <div>{rowData.id}</div>;
  };
  codeRenderer = (rowData: RowData) => {
    return <div>{rowData.code}</div>;
  };
  nameRenderer = (rowData: RowData) => {
    return <div>{rowData.name}</div>;
  };
  descriptionRenderer = (rowData: RowData) => {
    return <div>{rowData.description}</div>;
  };
  priceRenderer = (rowData: RowData) => {
    return <div>{rowData.price}</div>;
  };
  statusRenderer = (rowData: RowData) => {
    return <div>{this.getChip(rowData.status)}</div>;
  };
  severityRenderer = (rowData: RowData) => {
    return <div>{this.getChip(rowData.severity)}</div>;
  };
  dateRenderer = (rowData: RowData) => {
    return <DateFormatter data={rowData.date} />;
  };

  render() {
    const productsData = ProductService.getProductsData();
    console.log('Products are', this.state.products)
    console.log('State:', this.state);
    console.log('Props:', this.props);
    return (
      <div>
        <div>
          <h1>Product DataTable</h1>

          <CustomDataTable
            data={productsData}
            checkbox={true}
            sortField={this.state.sortField}
            sortOrder={this.state.sortOrder}
            onSortChange={this.handleSortChange}
            onSelectionChange={this.handleSelectionChange}
            scrollHeight={this.state.scrollHeight}
            scrollWidth={this.state.scrollWidth}
            scrollable={true}
            height="40%"
            width="100%"
            globalSearch={true} 
            resetIcon={false}          >
            <Column
              field={'id'}
              header={this.getHeader('id')} 
              body={this.IdRenderer}
              sortable={true}
            />
            <Column
              field={'code'}
              header={this.getHeader('code')} 
              body={this.codeRenderer}
            />
            <Column
              field={'name'}
              header={this.getHeader('name')}
              body={this.nameRenderer}
              sortable
            />
            <Column
              field={'description'}
              header={this.getHeader('description')}
              body={this.descriptionRenderer}
            />
            <Column
              field={'price'}
              header={this.getHeader('price')} 
              body={this.priceRenderer}
              sortable
            />
            <Column
              field={'status'}
              header={this.getHeader('status')} 
              body={this.statusRenderer}
            />
            <Column
              field={'severity'}
              header={this.getHeader('severity')}
              body={this.severityRenderer}
            />
            <Column
              field={'date'}
              header={this.getHeader('date')} 
              body={this.dateRenderer}
            />
          </CustomDataTable>
        </div>
        <div className='gtac'>
          <div className='title'>GTAC REF</div>
          <div className='div1'>Demo div1</div>
          <div className='div2'>Demo div2</div>
          <div className='gtac_table'>
            <CustomDataTable 
              data={productsData}
              checkbox={true}
              sortField={this.state.sortField}
              sortOrder={this.state.sortOrder}
              onSortChange={this.handleSortChange}
              onSelectionChange={this.handleSelectionChange}
              scrollHeight={this.state.scrollHeight}
              scrollWidth={this.state.scrollWidth}
              scrollable={true}
              height="40%"
              width="100%"
              globalSearch={false} 
              resetIcon={false}            >
              <Column
                field={'id'}
                header={this.getHeader('id')} 
                body={this.IdRenderer}
                sortable={true}
              />
              <Column
                field={'code'}
                header={this.getHeader('code')} 
                body={this.codeRenderer}
              />
              <Column
                field={'name'}
                header={this.getHeader('name')}
                body={this.nameRenderer}
                sortable
              />
              <Column
                field={'description'}
                header={this.getHeader('description')}
                body={this.descriptionRenderer}
              />
              <Column
                field={'price'}
                header={this.getHeader('price')} 
                body={this.priceRenderer}
                sortable
              />
              <Column
                field={'status'}
                header={this.getHeader('status')} 
                body={this.statusRenderer}
              />
              <Column
                field={'severity'}
                header={this.getHeader('severity')}
                body={this.severityRenderer}
              />
              <Column
                field={'date'}
                header={this.getHeader('date')} 
                body={this.dateRenderer}
              />
            </CustomDataTable>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className='filter'>
          <div className='title'>Filter Table</div>
          <div className='filter_table'>
            <CustomDataTable 
              data={this.state.products}
              checkbox={true}
              sortField={this.state.sortField}
              sortOrder={this.state.sortOrder}
              onSortChange={this.handleSortChange}
              onSelectionChange={this.handleSelectionChange}
              scrollHeight={this.state.scrollHeight}
              scrollWidth={this.state.scrollWidth}
              scrollable={true}
              height="40%"
              width="100%"
              globalSearch={true} 
              resetIcon={true}              >
              <Column
              field={'userId'}
              header={this.getHeader('user id')} 
              body={(rowData) => <div>{rowData.userId}</div>}
              sortable={true}
              filter
              />
              <Column
                field={'id'}
                header={this.getHeader('id')} 
                body={(rowData) => <div>{rowData.id}</div>}
              />
              <Column
                field={'title'}
                header={this.getHeader('title')}
                body={(rowData) => <div>{rowData.title}</div>}
                sortable
              />
              <Column
                field={'body'}
                header={this.getHeader('body')}
                body={(rowData) => <div>{rowData.body}</div>}
              />
              {/* <Column
                field={'price'}
                header={this.getHeader('price')} 
                body={this.priceRenderer}
                sortable
              />
              <Column
                field={'status'}
                header={this.getHeader('status')} 
                body={this.statusRenderer}
              />
              <Column
                field={'severity'}
                header={this.getHeader('severity')}
                body={this.severityRenderer}
              />
              <Column
                field={'date'}
                header={this.getHeader('date')} 
                body={this.dateRenderer}
              /> */}
            </CustomDataTable>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className='rowExp'>
          <div className='title'>Row Exp Table</div>
          <div className='row_table'>
            <CustomDataTable 
              data={productsData}
              checkbox={true}
              sortField={this.state.sortField}
              sortOrder={this.state.sortOrder}
              onSortChange={this.handleSortChange}
              onSelectionChange={this.handleSelectionChange}
              scrollHeight={this.state.scrollHeight}
              scrollWidth={this.state.scrollWidth}
              scrollable={true}
              height="40%"
              width="100%"
              globalSearch={true} 
              resetIcon={true}              >
              <Column
                field={'id'}
                header={this.getHeader('id')} 
                body={this.IdRenderer}
                sortable={true}
                filter
              />
              <Column
                field={'code'}
                header={this.getHeader('code')} 
                body={this.codeRenderer}
              />
              <Column
                field={'name'}
                header={this.getHeader('name')}
                body={this.nameRenderer}
                sortable
              />
              <Column
                field={'description'}
                header={this.getHeader('description')}
                body={this.descriptionRenderer}
              />
              <Column
                field={'price'}
                header={this.getHeader('price')} 
                body={this.priceRenderer}
                sortable
              />
              <Column
                field={'status'}
                header={this.getHeader('status')} 
                body={this.statusRenderer}
              />
              <Column
                field={'severity'}
                header={this.getHeader('severity')}
                body={this.severityRenderer}
              />
              <Column
                field={'date'}
                header={this.getHeader('date')} 
                body={this.dateRenderer}
              />
            </CustomDataTable>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

You can checkout out my code like how I am using the fetchData. As I am a beginner of react I don't have much idea about stores. Can someone please help me with this! Thanks in advance.